# java return String[] in method,String[].length is not correct

Tags: java

What I want is inserting datas into array String[],and then print the array values.
the returning String[] type method is

```
public String[] getRequirementDocIDofProject(String testprojectName)
        throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    String req_doc_ids[] = null;
    String str_sqlQuery = "select * from req_specs INNER JOIN nodes_hierarchy nh " + 
            "on nh.id=req_specs.testproject_id  " + 
            "INNER JOIN requirements reqs " + 
            "on req_specs.id =reqs.srs_id where nh.name='" + testprojectName + "'";
    int count = 0;
    int n = 0;
    initDB();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(str_sqlQuery);
    while (resultSet.next()){
        count = Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(1));
    }
    req_doc_ids = new String[count];

    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(str_sqlQuery);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        req_doc_ids[n] = resultSet.getString("req_doc_id");
        System.out.println("REQID=" + req_doc_ids[n]);
        n++;
    }
    close();
    System.out.println("n==" + n);
    return req_doc_ids;
}
```

the calling method code is

```
DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
String req_doc_ids[] = dbcon.getRequirementDocIDofProject("XXXX");
System.out.println(req_doc_ids.length);
```

the print message in Console is
REQID=TECH-6104
REQID=TECH-6686
REQID=TECH-5391
REQID=TECH-5965
REQID=TECH-6530
REQID=TECH-6729
REQID=TECH-7082
REQID=TECH-7107
REQID=TECH-7184
n==9
7166

why req_doc_ids.length 's value is 7166 rather than 9

Comment: Well you have `req_doc_ids=new String[count];` so the question is why is `count` 7166?

Comment: 7166 comes from the 1-th column of the result set - it's the value in the last row.

Comment: req_doc_ids=new String[count] what is the value of count here ?

Comment: As a side note: your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead of putting the value (`testprojectname`) directly into the query, please learn about parameterized SQL via `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

7166 comes from the 1-th column of the result set - it's the value in the last row.

```
while(resultSet.next()){
    count=Integer.parseInt(resultSet.getString(1));
}
```

Instead, you perhaps meant:

```
while(resultSet.next()){
    count++;
}
```

Mind you, this is an unnecessarily inefficient way to create the array. Use a `List` instead; or, use the method on the result set API to get the number of rows directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue has already been clarified by Andy and this answer is just an extension to help you with your current code.

Couple of improvements possible in your code.

1. Prefer using [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of `Statement` which is not safe and may be at risk to SQL Injection attack as already mentioned by Jon Skeet.
2. Why to run a db query twice which potentially could be a heavy query just to find out the number of records to correctly initialize your String array.
3. Use `List<String>` to store whatever number of rows you get and finally convert the list to array like shown in below code.
4. Get rid of so many unneeded variables and so many lines of code to make your code appear crisp and clear.

You may try changing your method to this one,

```
public String[] getRequirementDocIDofProject(String testprojectName)
        throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    List<String> reqDocIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str_sqlQuery = "select * from req_specs INNER JOIN nodes_hierarchy nh " + 
            "on nh.id=req_specs.testproject_id  " + 
            "INNER JOIN requirements reqs " + 
            "on req_specs.id =reqs.srs_id where nh.name='" + testprojectName + "'";

    initDB();
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(str_sqlQuery);
    while (resultSet.next()){
        System.out.println("REQID=" + resultSet.getString("req_doc_id"));
        reqDocIdList.add(resultSet.getString("req_doc_id"));
    }
    close();
    System.out.println("n==" + reqDocIdList.size());
    return reqDocIdList.toArray(new String[reqDocIdList.size()]);
}
```